# Omitting "being" after subject in absolute phrases

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, participles, absolute-clauses

As far as I know, we can omit "being" in the sentence 1 and 2.

> 1- He smiled at his girlfriend, her clothes ***(being)*** all muddy and
>   tattered.
>
> 2- His Ipad ***(being)*** dead, he felt bored.

Can I omit the "being" in these sentences below as well? If I cant, what is the difference?

> 3- I was preaparing the food , my friends ***being*** sick of waiting.
>   (I was preparing the food and my friends were sick of waiting)
>
> 4- The word “book” has a double meaning , the noun form ***being***  "a set
>   of pages inside a cover”, while the verb form is "to arrange to have a
>   seat etc. at a particular time in the future".

Comment: Please can you provide more context? Where did these phrases come from and how did you get to the conclusions you have drawn about where they can and can't be omitted?

Comment: 1 and 2 are the verbless analogues of the absolutes with "being". 3 and 4 are possible too.

Comment: It should be *he felt* ***bored***, not *he felt* ***boring***. (And *was* would be more common than *felt*.)

Comment: @BillJ Some native speakers told me that I couldn't omit "being" in 3 and 4. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Could you give your opinion on sentence 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

I would not omit "being" in any of these four cases, unless I were writing a novel or a poem.  I wouldn't say it's incorrect.  It may be a style issue.  If you added the word "with" it would be clearer:

The word “book” has a double meaning, with the noun form being "..."

With his iPad dead, he felt bored.

I was preparing the food, with my friends sick of waiting.

Comment: Thank you so much. I suppose this versions are okay too? : "With his iPad being dead, he felt bored." or "I was preparing the food, with my friends being sick of waiting."